# Is it possible to let play pick up changes in dependencies?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4

**Here's the short version**:

Should play pick up changes in it's dependencies?
When I change a jar file in the `/lib` dir in DEV mode, play recompiles, but the changes are not applied.

**And here in more detail**:

I'm currently setting up a new play app based on our current application.
We already have an existing project structure with modules, which I've put in the `/lib` dir. **That works fine so far**.

The problem now is related to the workflow in DEV mode:

When I make changes to one of those modules (replacing it's jar in the `/lib` dir), play recompiles (`[Info] Compiling ...`), but the changes are not applied.

I've also tried adding a jar as a managed dependency (`libraryDependencies += "group" % "module" % "1.0" from "file:///path/to/jar"`), but it behaves the same.

Is play/sbt supposed to pick up the changes in the jar file?

Notes:

- Just restarting the whole application is not practical since the initialization of our stuff (non-play) takes some time...
- Currently, we're using jrebel. I couldn't figure out how to setup this yet (and frankly play's reloading capability and jrebel is too much for me ;-))

Comment: I came to the conclusion that my approach is flawed:
Reloading dependent jars would most likely loose all state on any static fields (think of Singletons, DB connection pools, whatever - you cannot know). So it's not the way to go...

So I've tried to go the JRebel route and think I've found a way.
If anyone's interested, I've put up a repo here:  https://github.com/schoenberger/play-framework-java-jrebel

Answer (score 0):

Compiling should pick up the new jar files.

If this fails, you could try running `clean` and `test:compile` in sbt/play console.

**EDIT:**

You could start sbt/play on another terminal and run `~test:compile`.

This would watch for, and recompile your app as soon as it notices a new change.

Comment: Yes, if I restart the application, everything works (and the changes are picked up).
My problem is I want to use the reloading capability of the DEV mode.
I haven't seen play pick up the changes here, so far...